# Add Soap Tags to generated XML

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, spring-jms

I need to change this XML to the one below. I currently generate the existing xml using XSD, java util class that sets the values and marshal using Jibx and send the message using JMS. Any help would be appreciated. What's the simplest way to acieve this.

XSD for request:

```
<xsd:schema 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="Request">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    A request.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Header" type="Header" />
                <xsd:element name="RequestBody" type="RequestBody" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

XSD for header:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Header" abstract="true">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The definition of a Header.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="HeaderVersion" type="HeaderVersion" />
            <xsd:element name="ServiceName" type="ServiceName" />
            <xsd:element name="ServiceVersion" type="ServiceVersion" />
            <xsd:element name="ServiceType" type="ServiceType" />
            <xsd:element name="ApplicationId" type="ApplicationId" />           
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Existing generated XML:

```
<Request><Header><HeaderVersion>1.0</HeaderVersion><ServiceName>Service</ServiceName><ServiceVersion>1.0</ServiceVersion><ServiceType>search</ServiceType><ApplicationId>1</ApplicationId></Header><RequestBody><UserInfo><UserId>SYSTEM</UserId><RoleNames/></UserInfo><GetRequest><Type>123</Type></GetRequest></RequestBody></Request>
```

This should be generated instead to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <Header>
            <ServiceVersion>1.0</ServiceVersion>
            <ServiceName>Service</ServiceName>
            <HeaderVersion>1.0</HeaderVersion>
        </Header>
        <TimeStamp>
            <Millis>1429884619658</Millis>
            <Formatted>2015 04 24 14:10:19</Formatted>
        </TimeStamp>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns9:GetRequest xmlns="" xmlns:ns6="http://example.com/schemas/common" xmlns:ns7="http://example.com/schemas/service" xmlns:ns8="http://example.com/schemas/common" xmlns:ns9="http://example.com/schemas/service">
            <Type>123</Type>
        </ns9:GetRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you asking what should be the new XSD for Header to generate this ? Aslo for now I do not understand why you have an abstract Header type and in the existing XML no xsi:type attribute.

Comment: Yes the new XSD plus also any changes to the code. I have updated the question to include the xsd for the header. Hope this answers your question. Thanks so much.

Comment: Maybe you should change the title to "soap message over spring JMS" ? I could find a similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629366/architect-desperately-wants-to-use-soap-over-jms . Your request definition is far from a Soap:envelope message. There should be framework details helping for this, I don't think you have to generate the full soap:envelop manually, maybe only the header and the body apart.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reverse engineer the soap protocol.  I don't know spring, but I bet there's a soap library that will work with it.